# Proof of De-Morgan's law.

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

**The law states : $(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B' $**

Although I can do it using Venn diagrams, I tried it using this method:

Let $x$ be any arbitrary element which exists in the set $(A \cup B)'$

$x \in (A \cup B)'$

$\Longrightarrow  x \notin (A\cup B)$

$\Longrightarrow  x \notin A $  **and**  $x \notin B $

$\Longrightarrow  x \in A' $  **or**  $x \in B' $

But now I'm getting **or** so that means union , so the final proof which I'm getting is :

$(A \cup B)' = (A' \cup B') $

Please tell where I am going wrong.

Comment: $x \notin C$ is literally the same thing as $x \in C'$. So, you shouln't switch the *and* to *or* in the last implication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your last implication:  Why are you switching from "and" to "or"?  You shouldn't.

Your proof only leaves the job half done.  You have only proved $(A \cup B)' \subseteq A' \cap B'$.  To establish equality, you also need to prove the other containment:  if $x \in A' \cap B'$, then $x \in (A \cup B)'$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've gone wrong with your last statement.

I.E.
$\Longrightarrow  x \epsilon A' $ or  $ x \epsilon B'$

Note that $A'$includes $(A \cup B)'$ and $B-A$

And, $B'$includes $(A \cup B)'$ and $A-B$

So, according to your last statement, x can belong to $(A \cup B)'$, as well as $B-A$ or $A-B$. And that is not what you mean by your second last statement, i.e. $\Longrightarrow  x \notin A $ and  $ x \not in B'$

Thus, you shouldn't switch from AND to OR. You'll get the required relation, then.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. You correctly had $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$, which is precisely what it means to say that $x\in A'$ $\textbf{and}$ $x\in B'$. So $x\in A'\cap B'$. If $x\in A'\cap B'$, then $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B$, so $x$ is not in A or B, i.e., $x\notin A\cup B$. So $x\in (A\cup B)'$.